# How do I set a Windows Service to start automatically in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-services

If I know a service name, and have enough permission, how do I set a Windows Service to be auto-restart in PowerShell?

I am using PowerShell 1.0, and the OS is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be asking for:

```
Set-Service [service name] -startuptype automatic
```

See:

```
> get-help set-service

NAME
    Set-Service

SYNOPSIS
    Starts, stops, and suspends a service, and changes its properties.


SYNTAX
    Set-Service [-StartupType {Automatic | Manual | Disabled}] [-DisplayName <string>] [-PassThru] [-Status <string>] [
    -InputObject <ServiceController>] [-Description <string>] [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-confirm] [-whatif] [<CommonP
    arameters>]

    Set-Service [-Status <string>] [-StartupType {Automatic | Manual | Disabled}] [-Description <string>] [-Name] <stri
    ng> [-PassThru] [-DisplayName <string>] [-ComputerName <string[]>] [-confirm] [-whatif] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: It's for setting service stratup mode. But I suppose, George want to configure service for auto-restart when it crashes.

Comment: Error information when executing your command => Set-Service : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'starttyp
e'.

Comment: HawX, I want to set it to be automatic start during system start-up.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I have a typo, should use startuptype other than starttype.

Comment: I have a related question here, appreciate if you could help. :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218969/error-stopping-a-windows-service