# Error stopping a Windows Service

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I am using PowerShell 1.0 on Windows Server 2003 x64. When executing the following statement, there is error below. Not every time this error occurs, and if this error occurs and I execute this command again, there is no error again! It is so weird. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
Stop-Service "SQLServerAgent" -Force -ErrorAction:stop

WARNING: Waiting for service 'SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER) (SQLSERVERAGENT)' 
to finish stopping...
out-lineoutput : The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected. Do n
ot use a handle simultaneously in one FileStream and in Win32 code or another F
ileStream. This may cause data loss.
```

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is bug in PowerShell.

Please see Lee Holmes' post for a Workaround: [The OS handle's position is not what FileStream expected](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/07/30/workaround-the-os-handles-position-is-not-what-filestream-expected/)

Answer (score 0):

Workarounds didn't work for me. Switched to using start-transcript at the start of the script instead. Doesn't the output of the programs you run, but there are workarounds.